# Strange issue with CodeIgniter database access

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am developing an web app using CodeIgniter 2.2. I have used near about 20 tables and different models, controllers and views. Each and every query runs fine and I am getting desired result.

Yesterday I coded a simple query to get data from my database. the query returns the result when I run it in mysql. But when I return the output from CodeIgniter result set it returns zero (0) rows.

I am giving you the code details that I used for debugging.

My table ( SQLFIDDLE Link [Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cd56e/1/0) )

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `goal` (
  `goal_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sub_program_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `emp_id` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `goal_desc` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  `goal_value` int(9) NOT NULL,
  `actual_value` int(9) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `start_date` date NOT NULL,
  `end_date` datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
);
ALTER TABLE `goal`
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`goal_id`);
ALTER TABLE `goal`
MODIFY `goal_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=34;
INSERT INTO `goal` 
(`goal_id`, `sub_program_id`, `emp_id`, `goal_desc`, `goal_value`, `start_date`, `actual_value`, `end_date`) 
VALUES
(1, 103, 95113, 'dxgdsfg', 34, '2015-07-30', 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00'),
(2, 103, 920836, 'cvbn', 34, '2015-07-30', 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00'),
(3, 101, 95113, 'fgh', 45, '2015-07-29', 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00'),
(4, 101, 95113, 'fgh', 45, '2015-07-29', 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00'),
(5, 103, 95113, 'fgh', 45, '2015-07-29', 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00'),
(6, 101, 920836, 'fgh', 45, '2015-07-29', 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00'),
(7, 101, 95113, 'fgh', 45, '2015-07-29', 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00')
```

When I try to run this query from mysql

```
SELECT sub_program_id, max(goal_id) as new_goal FROM goal where emp_id='95113' group by sub_program_id
```

I am getting 2 rows:

[image]

I am doing the same in CodeIgniter and my debugging code is as below.

```
$qbik="SELECT sub_program_id, max(goal_id) as new_goal FROM goal where emp_id='95113' group by sub_program_id";
$qrbik=$this->db->query($qbik);
if($qrbik)
    echo '<br>Number of rows: '.$qrbik->num_rows();
$x=$qrbik->result();
echo '<br>Result: '; print_r($x);
echo '<br>SQL Query: '.$qbik;
echo '<br>Last Query that run on database using codeigniter: '.$this->db->last_query();
exit;
```

Output from CodeIgniter:

[image]

This is very strange to me.

Comment: emp_id='95113' write like emp_id=95113 and check

Comment: It is working perfectly in my end !!!

Comment: I checked both way emp_id='95113' and emp_id=95113, but still same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you community for all of your effort. I specially thanks @bugfixer, @abdulla, @prasant, @ariful and @user1048123.

I got my answer. This is not CodeIgniter or database issue. This issue arise due to database miss configuration. The codeigniter is pointed to old database.

Comment: You forgot to check the most basic thing before running your code.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
function result()
    {
        $query=$this->db->query("SELECT sub_program_id, max(goal_id) as new_goal FROM goal where emp_id='95113' group by sub_program_id");
        $result = $query->result_array();//assign data to objective array            
        $count = count($result);//get count

        if (!empty($count))
        {
            //if $result having one or more answer it comes to this
            echo '<br>Number of rows: '.$count;
            echo '<br>Result: '.print_r($result);
            //echo '<br>SQL Query:'.$qbik;
            //echo '<br>Last Query that run on database using codeigniter: '.$this->db->last_query();

        }
        else
        {
           echo 'Nothing selected form database';
        }
    }
```

Comment: Nothing selected form database. Same issue. What I identify the issue is the where condition for emp_id=95113 is returning false when I run the query from CodeIgniter, but works perfectly when I run it through phpmyadmin.

Comment: @Bikram Pahi - open ur index.php and check which environment u r using.

Comment: @BikramPahi try with `emp_id='95113'`

Comment: @Bugfixer I am using my local server.

Comment: @BikramPahi - No i am asking about environment.check ur project index.php **define('ENVIRONMENT', 'production');**.If it is production then change it to **development** like this  **define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');**

Comment: My environment is development;

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will helps you...

```
    $this->db->select('sub_program_id, max(goal_id) as new_goal');
    $this->db->from('goal');
    $this->db->where('emp_id',95113);
    $this->db->group_by('sub_program_id');
    $q = $this->db->get();
    if ($q->num_rows() > 0) {
        print_r($q->result());
    }
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but still the out put is same.